# After publishing application on IIS server mimetype of xlsx file returning application/octet-stream

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, mime-types

I am trying to fetch mime type from file content. It is working fine on IIS Express and IIS configured on windows 10 locally, but when I published application to windows 2012 server. Mime of xlsx file returning application/octet-stream.

```
Public Shared Function GetMimeType(ByVal file As String) As String
        Dim mime As String = Nothing
        Dim MaxContent As Integer = CInt(New FileInfo(file).Length)
        If MaxContent > 4096 Then
            MaxContent = 4096
        End If

        Dim fs As New FileStream(file, FileMode.Open)

        Dim buf(MaxContent) As Byte
        fs.Read(buf, 0, MaxContent)
        fs.Close()
        Dim result As Integer = FindMimeFromData(IntPtr.Zero, file, buf, MaxContent, Nothing, 0, mime, 0)

        Return mime
    End Function

    <DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling:=True, 

        SetLastError:=False)>
            Private Shared Function FindMimeFromData(
                ByVal pBC As IntPtr,
                <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)>
                ByVal pwzUrl As String,
                <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType:=UnmanagedType.I1, SizeParamIndex:=3)> ByVal _
                pBuffer As Byte(),
                ByVal cbSize As Integer,
                <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)>
                ByVal pwzMimeProposed As String,
                ByVal dwMimeFlags As Integer,
                <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)>
                ByRef ppwzMimeOut As String,
                ByVal dwReserved As Integer) As Integer
            End Function
```

I expect to get output of file xlsx as `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

[IIS MimeType Scanpshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbuw6.png)

Comment: Have you checked the actual mime mappings under MIME Types tab in the IIS management console?

Comment: Could you please tell us how you fetch the mime type?

Comment: @WiktorZychla yes i have checked that detail in IIS managemen console.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal i have updated the post you can see the code now.

Comment: could you share iis mime type snapshot for  xlsx file?

Comment: please see i have mentioned in above post.